# Select least revision ID from audit of entities

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database that is AUD_entitiy_type. I have a very simple query:

```
SELECT id, REV, status_1, status_2, status_3, status_4, code
FROM AUD_entitiy_type --Audit table
WHERE (status_1 LIKE 'A%' AND status_2 IS NULL
    OR (status_1 LIKE 'B%' AND status_2 IS NULL)
    OR (status_1 LIKE 'C%' AND status_2 IS NULL))
```

Essentially I get all entities that had a status_1 of A, B or C (can be A1, A2...).

The audit table has an entry for every update that happens to an entity ie A2 changes to B1.

With the query I get results like

```
id    REV    status_1    status_2    status_3    status_4
1     100    A1          NULL        NULL        NULL
1     112    B1          NULL        NULL        NULL
1     131    A3          NULL        NULL        NULL
2     135    A1          NULL        NULL        NULL
3     142    A6          NULL        NULL        NULL
```

What I need is in cases where there are multiple entities with the same id (1 above) get the one with the lowest REV (100 above).

My research is not yielding much unfortunately because I am not sure the keywords to use. Have min value gives `having` and `min` which does not appear to be what I am looking for since in the example I still want 2 and 3.

There could have been a lot of normalization here I know that but 5 years ago I did not work here and this application is currently live (I have a JIRA for that update ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Window Function (ROW_NUMBER) inside a subquery.

```
SELECT a.id, a.REV, a.status_1, a.status_2, a.status_3, a.status_4, a.code
FROM (
    SELECT id, REV, status_1, status_2, status_3, status_4, code,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY REV) AS RowNumber
    FROM AUD_entitiy_type --Audit table
    WHERE (status_1 LIKE 'A%' AND status_2 IS NULL
        OR (status_1 LIKE 'B%' AND status_2 IS NULL)
        OR (status_1 LIKE 'C%' AND status_2 IS NULL))
) a
WHERE
    a.RowNumber = 1;
```